# Is it able to store Firebase user to our own database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

If I use the user registration and login through the firebase authentication, the user information are stored in the firebase database side. How can I get the user information (such as FirstName, LastName, Gender and etc.) and store in my own database? Is it use the access token to call my API to check the user identity?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use a cloud functions to triggers when user was created.

```
exports.userCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.

  // Write insert email, displayName, ... to your own database.
});
```

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Answer (score 2):

When a user registers for your app using Firebase Authentication, no information is sent to your Firebase database by default...they only have an Auth account.

You need to *manually* collect and send information to your database. Once a user is authenticated within your app, you can listen for their Auth user info with [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Lotsa folks then use the uid as the key in their database and store profile info below that.